# Xcode8 + OpenCV3.1: function suggestion using C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, autocomplete

I have a question about Xcode and OpenCV.

I want to use `resize` function which is implemented in OpenCV 3.1

This is its document:

```
resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size dsize, double fx=0, double fy=0, int interpolation=INTER_LINEAR )
```

but in my Xcode8, it only give me the function as below when I type `resize`:

```
resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size size)
```

[image]

As you can see, there isn't `fx`, `fy`, `interpolation`.

Though it is optional parameter, but is it any way to show all the parameters in suggestion?